# Display: none doesn't work on mobile

Tags: css, sass

I have a problem with display property on mobile. Display: none doesn't work at all. I'm using SASS. This is my code:

```
main {
  display: none;
}

@media(min-width: $mobile-breakpoint) {
  main {
    height: 800px;
    display: flex;
    background-color: inherit;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url("./images/main.jpg");
  }
}
```

Comment: well, you seem to have trouble with CSS in general like your previous question but you need to show us more code so that we can identify the issue

Comment: in `$mobile-breakpoint` you have used `display: flex;` overnighting your previous style. So how should it be `display: none`.??

Comment: There is display: flex from 768px, but I need to have display: none from 0 to 768px.

Comment: breakpoint should be from 0 - 767 (small screen)

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: none` within the mobile breakpoint.
Example:

```
@media(min-width: $mobile-breakpoint) {
 main {
 height: 800px;
 display: none;
 background-color: inherit;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-image: url("./images/main.jpg");
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't need display: none after breakpoint, I need to have display: none from 0px to 768px. At this moment display: flex is everywhere, but it is set on min-width: 768px.